# Live oak brown spots on leaves in south Florida

Tags: diseases, oak, leaf

I am hoping someone might be able to identify the disease shown on these live oak tree leaves. Hoping it’s not oak wilt. If there’s a recommendation on treatment that would be great. Thanks!

[image: oak disease]

[image: oak disease leaf]

[image: oak leaf]

Comment: Where is this? Southern North America? And which species please. Looks fungal. The browning is not following the veins, so not Oak Wilt.

Comment: It’s near Tampa Florida. I was also thinking fungus. Curious if I should maybe try to spray the tree or maybe an injection would be best